# How can I change Image in Listview during runtime in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to change the picture in the cell when the user clicks on the picture. The initial picture is the "right arrow" and when the user clicks the "right arrow" it should be "red x" but the icon does not change. The value of property (Binding value[3]) changes every time to 0 and 1 so it works fine.

Here is my code:

```
<GridViewColumn  Header="Functions">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Image x:Name="MoveImg"  Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Move Losses" MaxWidth="20" MaxHeight="20" Margin="3,3,3,3" MouseLeftButtonUp="MoveImg_MouseLeftButtonUp" >
                                                    <Image.Style>
                                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value[3]}" Value="1">
                                                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/x.ico"/>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value[3]}" Value="0">
                                                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/right_arrow.png"/>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </Image.Style>
                                                </Image>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
```

And the code in DtListView.xaml.cs

```
Dictionary<string, double[]> prDict = new Dictionary<string, double[]>();
Dictionary<string, string[]> lossTransferDict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
public Dictionary<string, double[]> PrDict { get => prDict; set => prDict = value; }

 public DtListView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


 private void MoveImg_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {



            if (TopLossesLv.SelectedItems != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double[]> item in TopLossesLv.SelectedItems)
                {
                    if (!lossTransferDict.ContainsKey(item.Key))
                    {
                        lossTransferDict.Add(item.Key, new string[4] { line, item.Value[0].ToString(), item.Value[1].ToString(), item.Value[2].ToString()});
                        prDict[item.Key][3] = 1; // Modify Value for Picture change

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lossTransferDict.Remove(item.Key);
                        prDict[item.Key][3] = 0; // Modify Value for Picture change

                    }


                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: The source property of the Binding of a DataTrigger must obviously fire a change notification, which can't be done by `Value[3]`.

Comment: I assume that `Value`  is an array? Changing the value of an array (or any other `IEnumerable`) does not raise the `INotifyProeprtyChanged.PropertyChanged` event. Without this event the triggers are not executing. The binding engine or dependency property system relies on the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event in order to track property changes.

Comment: To allow a dynamic data binding, `Value[3]` must be a property, which either raises the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event or is a `DependencyProperty` defined on an `DependencyObject`.

Comment: @BionicCode The value is part of the Dictionary<string, double[]>

Comment: This is not C. This is C#. C# is _object oriented_. Binding to an array is not a good idea. Instead bind to objects. From your code it looks like you are binding the `DataGrid` to the `PrDict` dictionary, am I correct? Instead of binding to a dictionary of arrays you should bind to a collection of objects. To do this, you would need to convert the array into a class, which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Each field of the array becomes a class property. You should apply this refactoring to all you items sources where they bind to arrays of values.

Comment: At the end you should be able to bind to lists only. Avoid binding to dictionaries or arrays. I don't have enough information about your context, so I can't go into detail here. E.g. what is `TopLossesLv` displaying and how does it relate to `DtListView`? Why does `TopLossesLv.SelectedItem` map to the items of `PrDict`? If you need a this mapping you _can_ use the dictionary for this, but don't bind a control to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not C. This is C#. C# is object oriented. Binding to an array of related values is not a good idea for many reasons. Instead bind to an object, that encapsulates the related values of the array.

Instead of binding to a dictionary of arrays, you should bind to a collection of objects. To do this, you would need to convert the array into a class, which implements [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8#examples).
Each field of the array becomes a class property. You should apply this refactoring to all your `Binding.Source`, where the source is an arrays of values. At the end you should be able to bind to lists only.

Avoid binding controls to dictionaries or arrays.

This is a simple example how to use objects (data models) to populate a `ListView` and change the `GridView` cell content (the `Image`) based on the value of a property `SimpleDataObject.IsActive` of the data model `SimpleDataObject`:

**SimpleDataObject.cs**

```
class SimpleDataObject : INotifyPropertyChaged
{ 
  // Constructor
  public SimpleDataObject(string data) => this.DataValue = data;

  private bool isActive;
  public bool IsActive
  {
    get => this.isActive;
    set
    {
      this.isActive = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }   

  private string dataValue;
  public string DataValue
  {
    get => this.dataValue;
    set
    {
      this.dataValue = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }   

  #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  #endregion
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
// Binding source
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChaged
{ 
  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.SimpleDataObjects = new ObservableCollection<SimpleDataObject>() 
    {
      new SimpleDataObject("Data value 1"),
      new SimpleDataObject("Data value 2"),
      new SimpleDataObject("Data value 3")
    }
  }

  public ObservableCollection<SimpleDataObject> SimpleDataObjects { get; set; }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private void OnImageMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    var image = sender as Image;
    var dataItem = image.DataContext as SimpleDataObject;
    dataItem.IsActive = true; // Toggle image
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SimpleDataObjects}">
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
        <GridView.Columns>
          <GridViewColumn  Header="Functions">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SimpleDataObject}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataValue}"/>

                  <Image MouseLeftButtonUp="OnImageMouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <Image.Style>
                      <Style TargetType="Image">

                        <!-- Default value. Applies when the observed property IsActive returns false -->
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/right_arrow.png" />

                        <Style.Triggers>
                          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/x.ico" />
                          </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                      </Style>
                    </Image.Style>
                  </Image>
                </StackPanel>
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView.Columns>
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have done based on your comment. I have created a class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged and also changed the double array to class properties in Dictionary.

Comment: Exactly! When the user clicks on the image that changes as expected.